# Django 1.4 RegexUrlResolver Object not callable

Tags: python, django, url

I'm using a bit of old code. From what I've read there is nothing on the internet regarding this error however now I've started using the code again but what worked in previous versions is no longer working

In urls.py

```
(r'^blog/detail/(?P<slug_id>[-w]+/$', 'blog.views.detailView'),
```

Error thrown by this

```
'RegexURLResolver' object is not callable
```

I cannot find any issues to using this method anywhere for Django 1.4?

Comment: Show the rest of your urls.py. You've got a missing/misplaced comma somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your regex - perhaps that will help? If not, I will delete this. Just guessing a bad regex and an error that says Regex in it could cause this...

```
(r'^blog/detail/(?P<slug_id>[-w]+/$', 'blog.views.detailView'),
```

Should be

```
(r'^blog/detail/(?P<slug_id>[-w]+)/$', 'blog.views.detailView'),
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed a comma in your urlpatterns tuple.

Python tries to call objects that are followed by a pair of brackets. So if you have

```
( 
 (a, b, c),
 (d, e, f)
)
```

that's a 2-tuple of 3-tuples, but if you have

```
( 
 (a, b, c)
 (d, e, f)
)
```

you'll get this error, since it's trying to call the first tuple with the second tuple as arguments.